# PHP Issue with getting file contents

Tags: php

I'm currently having an issue where I am trying to get 2 player names, and then display them like this:

```
Same TimeStamp
Player1
Player2
```

Unfortunately I can only get it like This

```
Logs of Player 1
13:04 Player 2 attacked player 1 and dealt 1 damage
-
-
-
-
-
Logs of Player 2
13:04 Player 2 attacked player 1 and dealt 1 damage
```

I cant get them to show after each other when the timestamp is the same

currently this is my code

```
<?php
$now = date ('m_d_y');
$file = "server_log_".$now.".txt";
$searchfor = ($_POST['name']);
$searchfor2 = ($_POST['name2']);

if ($searchfor !=""){
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/\b.*$pattern.*\b/i"; 

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches For Player 1:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found For Player 1";
}
}
else{
  echo "No Name Input";
  }
?>
```

What I want is when both the player names are searched for that it will find both logs and just display them right after each other instead of splitting the logs up.

currently player 2 logs only show when player 1 logs are finished

Example How it should not be

```
 17:43:37 - Admin TA_Kiki
 17:46:01 - Admin TA_Kiki
 17:47:15 - Admin TA_Kiki
 17:45:28 - SO_Peter has joined the game with ID: 1390151 and has administrator rights
```

Example How it Should be

```
 17:43:37 - Admin TA_Kiki
 17:45:28 - SO_Peter has joined the game with ID: 1390151 and has administrator rights. 
 17:46:01 - Admin TA_Kiki
 17:47:15 - Admin TA_Kiki
```

And how do i put both the variables $searchfor and $searchfor 2 in the same pattern

in this case

$searchfor = TA_Kiki
$searchfor2 = SO_Peter

Also searchfor2 has to be an option the script must be able to avoid when nothing is filled in for searchfor2

Comment: This is one of the reasons why we use DBMSs

Answer (score 0):

you can try sorting the matches array before printing it:

```
    ...
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
        echo "Found matches For Player 1:\n";
        sort($matches[0]);
        echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: i forgot to say this $searchfor = ($_POST['name']); has to be $searchfor = ($_POST['name']); 
$searchfor2 = ($_POST['name2']);
How would i put the 2 variables in the pattern to search for than find it and than sort it?